# How to edit a file to increase the size by adding white spaces at end in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, gauge

I want to first create a copy of a file and then check the size of the file and if the size is less than 1 MB then add white spaces at end of the file to make it 1 MB size.

I have copied the using below code but I am getting any help for adding white spaces at end of the file.

```py
from shutil import copyfile
copyfile(self.actualfile,self.copyfile)
```

Comment: Provide more description and what are self.actualfile,self.copyfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
import os

filename = 'file.txt'

size = os.stat(filename).st_size

f = open(filename, "a+")
f.write(" " * (1024*1024 - size))
f.close();
```

Comment: it's going to work well (as per the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq). However, I agree, it would be better to insert size check.

Comment: I beg your pardon.  You are quite right. Either a check, or a comment that one is not required.

Comment: I did this and it worked for me actual_size = os.path.getsize(self.copyfile)
        x = " " * (int(size)-actual_size)
        with open(self.copyfile, "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            f.write(x)      
        print("Size (In bytes) of '%s':" %os.path.getsize(self.copyfile))

Answer (score 0):

This uses `pathlib` from newer Pythons to simplify getting the file's size and adding *exactly* the padding you want.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pathlib
import shutil

destfile = pathlib.Path("/tmp/foo")
shutil.copyfile(__file__, destfile)

required_padding = 1024 * 1024 - destfile.stat().st_size
if required_padding > 0:
    with destfile.open("ab") as outfile:
        outfile.write(b" " * required_padding)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
with open(self.actualfile, 'r') as fin:
    with open(self.copyfile, 'w') as fout:
        print('{:<1048756}'.format(fin.read()), file=fout)
```

Comment: What is `contents`? Also, this does not check the size of the file, rather it prints 1024 characters _regardless_ of the current file size. The OP said "_if the size is less than 1 MB then add white spaces at end of the file to make it 1 MB size._".

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
actual_size = os.path.getsize(self.copyfile)
    x = " " * (int(size)-actual_size)
    with open(self.copyfile, "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(x)      
    print("Size (In bytes) of '%s':" %os.path.getsize(self.copyfile))
```